# Failed to parse plugin descriptor for Oracle maven sync plugin

Tags: oracle, maven-plugin, osb

I'm following instructions on this page to configure the Oracle Service Bus development Maven plug-in.
https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/soacs_gs/OSBDV/osb-maven.htm#OSBDV88450
I'm able to install the sync plugin but running the command to seed the Oracle Service Bus development Maven plug-in into the Maven repository fails with this error:
Failed to parse plugin descriptor for com.oracle.maven:oracle-
0-0 (C:\path\to.m2\repository\com\oracle\maven\oracle-ma
0\oracle-maven-sync-12.1.3-0-0.jar): error in opening zip file.

The jar file may be corrupted? But it came from Oracle's website when I downloaded Weblogic 12.1.3...or can there be another problem?

Answer (score 1):

Got it.
I accidentally downloaded the wrong weblogic installation package: a 200 MB update instead of the full 800 MB one.
What a waste of time... :-)